# Getting NaN as output in Javascript Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a Simple Calculator using JavaScript. I wrote a function calculate() to calculate the result. But I am getting NaN as output even though I've used parseInt().

The HTML code is :

```
<div class="row" id="display">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!--display here-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="func">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="myFunction(this)">1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="myFunction(this)">2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="myFunction(this)">3</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="myFunction(this)">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="func">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" id="zero-btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">0</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="myFunction(this)">.</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="calculate()">=</button>
        </div>
```

Javascript function:

```
function myFunction(elem) {
    var box = document.getElementById("display");
    box.innerHTML = box.innerHTML+elem.innerHTML;
}

function calculate(){
    var str = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
    var pos=str.search(/[+-/*]/);
    var a= str.slice(0,pos);
    var b = str.slice(pos+1,str.length);
    var op1 = parseInt(a);
    var op2 = parseInt(b);
    var res=0;
    switch(str[pos]){
        case '+':
        res = op1+op2;
        break;
        case '-':
        res = op1-op2;
        break;
        case '*':
        res = op1*op2;
        break;
        case '/':
        res = op1/op2;
        break;
        default:
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "ERROR";
    }
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: print value of `op1` and `op2` and check value is correct integer.

Comment: Then check the steps that generate `op1` and `op2`...

Comment: @Drashti thats the issue, problem in getting that input value.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming because of the HTML code.
There shouldn't be anything inside the element with 'display' id.
The correct code is :

```
<div class="row" id="display">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the str var contains :

```
<div class=\"col-sm-12\">
        <!--display here-->
</div>
Calculation
```

So when you try to split based on the first occurrence of `+-/*` you are getting `<div class=\"col"` (it stops there cause the next character of the class name is a `-` ), when you try to convert that string to a number JS tells you that that is not a number.

Try replacing your HTML with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row" id="display">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="func">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="myFunction(this)">1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="myFunction(this)">2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="myFunction(this)">3</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="myFunction(this)">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="func">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" id="zero-btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">0</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="myFunction(this)">.</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" onclick="calculate()">=</button>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best way to make calculator but according to your way 
First edit Html code and add Display Id to the col Div

```
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="display">

  </div>
```

then in javascript 
get actual operator , Search won't used , Check it's function again ,
I found that way easy to get operator

```
  var str = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
  var operator = "";
  if (str.indexOf('+') > -1) {
    operator = "+";
  }else if (str.indexOf('-') > -1) {
    operator = "-";
  }else if (str.indexOf('*') > -1) {
    operator = "/";
  }else if (str.indexOf('/') > -1) {
    operator = "/";
  }
```

then use split to get numbers , keeping in mind more than two numbers won't work

```
   var NumberOne = str.split(operator)[0];
   var NumberTwo = str.split(operator)[1];
```

parse number to int

```
   var op1 = parseInt(NumberOne);
   var op2 = parseInt(NumberTwo);
```

Switch the Operator variable

```
   switch(operator){ ..
   ....
```

Now it works